# Collapsing (hiding) and showing all chrome extensions' icons simultaneously

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm wondering if there is a way to collapse (hide) and show all the extensions' icons in google chrome. I searched a solution online, but without any success. My address bar is so small because there are many icons and I need all of them sometimes.
I know that I can hide them in the Extensions icon of chrome, but it is not comfortable because there there are icons of extensions that I don't use.